# How to read the user input line by line until Ctrl+D and include the line where Ctrl+D was typed

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, read, user-input

This script takes the user input line after line, and executes `myfunction` on every line

```
#!/bin/bash
SENTENCE=""

while read word
do
    myfunction $word"
done
echo $SENTENCE
```

To stop the input, the user has to press `[ENTER]` and then `Ctrl+D`.

How can I rebuild my script to end only with `Ctrl+D` and process the  line where `Ctrl+D` was pressed.

Comment: What is included in "myfunction"? I run your example, i used a simple `function myfunction { echo "you pressed $1" ; };`  and as soon as i press control D loop ends `echo $sentence` is performed and script exits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To do that, you'd have to read character by character, not line by line.

Why? The shell very likely uses the standard C library function `read()`
to read the data that the user is typing in, and that function returns
the number of bytes actually read. If it returns zero, that means it has
encountered EOF (see the `read(2)` manual; `man 2 read`). Note that EOF
isn't a character but a condition, i.e. the condition "there is nothing
more to be read", *end-of-file*.

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> sends an [*end-of-transmission character*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)
(EOT, ASCII character code 4, `$'\04'` in `bash`) to the terminal
driver. This has the effect of sending whatever there is to send to the
waiting `read()` call of the shell.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> halfway through
entering the text on a line, whatever you have typed so far is
sent to the shell<sup>1</sup>. This means that if you enter
<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice after having typed something on
a line, the first one will send some data, and the second one will
send *nothing*, and the `read()` call will return zero and the shell
interpret that as EOF. Likewise, if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed
by <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, the shell gets EOF at once as there
wasn't any data to send.

So how to avoid having to type <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice?

As I said, read single characters. When you use the `read` shell
built-in command, it probably has an input buffer and asks `read()` to
read a maximum of that many characters from the input stream (maybe 16
kb or so). This means that the shell will get a bunch of 16 kb chunks
of input, followed by a chunk that may be less than 16 kb, followed by
zero bytes (EOF). Once encountering the end of input (or a newline, or a
specified delimiter), control is returned to the script.

If you use `read -n 1` to read a single character, the shell will use
a buffer of a single byte in its call to `read()`, i.e. it will sit in
a tight loop reading character by character, returning control to the
shell script after each one.

The only issue with `read -n` is that it sets the terminal to "raw
mode", which means that characters are sent as they are without any
interpretation.  For example, if you press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>,
you'll get a literal EOT character in your string.  So we have to check
for that. This also has the side-effect that the user will be unable to edit the line before submitting it to the script, for example by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, or by using <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> (to delete the previous word) or <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> (to delete to the beginning of the line).

**To make a long story short:** The following is the final loop that your
`bash` script needs to do to read a line of input, while at the same time
allowing the user to interrupt the input at any time by pressing
<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>:

```
while true; do
    line=''

    while IFS= read -r -N 1 ch; do
        case "$ch" in
            $'\04') got_eot=1   ;&
            $'\n')  break       ;;
            *)      line="$line$ch" ;;
        esac
    done

    printf 'line: "%s"\n' "$line"

    if (( got_eot )); then
        break
    fi
done
```

Without going into too much detail about this:

- `IFS=` clears the `IFS` variable. Without this, we would not be able to read spaces. I use `read -N` instead of `read -n`, otherwise we wouldn't be able to detect newlines. The `-r` option to `read` enables us to read backslashes properly.
- The `case` statement acts on each read character (`$ch`). If an EOT (`$'\04'`) is detected, it sets `got_eot` to 1 and then falls through to the `break` statement which gets it out of the inner loop. If a newline (`$'\n'`) is detected, it just breaks out of the inner loop. Otherwise it adds the character to the end of the `line` variable.
- After the loop, the line is printed to standard output. This would be where you call your script or function that uses `"$line"`. If we got here by detecting an EOT, we exit the outermost loop.

<sup>1</sup> You may test this by running `cat >file` in one terminal
and `tail -f file` in another, and then enter a partial line into the
`cat` and press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to see what happens in the
output of `tail`.

---

For `ksh93` users: The loop above will read a carriage return character rather than a newline character in `ksh93`, which means that the test for `$'\n'` will need to change to a test for `$'\r'`.  The shell will also display these as `^M`.

To work around this:

```
stty_saved="$( stty -g )"
stty -echoctl

# the loop goes here, with $'\n' replaced by $'\r'

stty "$stty_saved"
```

You might also want to output a newline explicitly just before the `break` to get exactly the same behaviour as in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

In the default mode of the terminal device, the `read()` system call (when called with large enough a buffer) would lead full lines. The only times when the read data would not end in a newline character would be when you press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

In my tests (on Linux, FreeBSD and Solaris), a single `read()` only ever yields one single line even if the user has entered more by the time `read()` is called. The only case where the read data could contain more than one line would be when the user enters a newline as <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> (the literal-next character followed by a literal newline character (as opposed to a carriage-return converted to newline when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)).

The `read` shell builtin however reads the input one byte at a time until it sees a newline character or end of file. That *end of file* would be when `read(0, buf, 1)` returns 0 which can only happen when you press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on an empty line.

Here, you'd want to do large reads and detect the <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> when the input doesn't end in a newline character.

You can't  do that with the `read` builtin, but you could do it with the `sysread` builtin of `zsh`.

If you want to account for the user typing `^V^J`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system # for sysread

myfunction() printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$1"

lines=('')
while (($#lines)); do
  if (($#lines == 1)) && [[ $lines[1] == '' ]]; then
    sysread
    lines=("${(@f)REPLY}") # split on newline
    continue
  fi

  # pop one line
  line=$lines[1]
  lines[1]=()

  myfunction "$line"
done
```

If you want to consider `foo^V^Jbar` as a single record (with an embedded newline), that is assume each `read()` returns one record:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/system # for sysread

myfunction() printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$1"

finished=false
while ! $finished && sysread line; do
  if [[ $line = *$'\n' ]]; then
    line=${line%?} # strip the newline
  else
    finished=true
  fi

  myfunction "$line"
done
```

Alternatively, with `zsh`, you could use `zsh`'s own advanced line editor to input the data and map `^D` there to a widget that signals the end of input:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
myfunction() printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$1"

finished=false
finish() {
  finished=true
  zle .accept-line
}

zle -N finish
bindkey '^D' finish

while ! $finished && line= && vared line; do
  myfunction "$line"
done
```

With `bash` or other POSIX shells, for an equivalent of the `sysread` approach, you could do something approaching by using `dd` to do the `read()` system calls:

```
#! /bin/sh -

sysread() {
  # add a . to preserve the trailing newlines
  REPLY=$(dd bs=8192 count=1 2> /dev/null; echo .)
  REPLY=${REPLY%?} # strip the .
  [ -n "$REPLY" ]
}

myfunction() { printf 'Got: <%s>\n' "$1"; }
nl='
'

finished=false
while ! "$finished" && sysread; do
  case $REPLY in
    (*"$nl") line=${REPLY%?};; # strip the newline
    (*) line=$REPLY finished=true
  esac

  myfunction "$line"
done
```

Comment: I always thought `zsh` suffered from "feature bloat", but it turns out that some of the features seems to be quite handy at times. About the `dd` in the `sh` script: could you comment on why you read `8192` bytes (8kb)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, 8192 is what zsh `sysread` uses by default (also the maximum supported there). What _feature_ of `zsh` do you not find useful? Note that `zsh` code is also in different dynamically modules, so the _bloat_ doesn't affect it as much as other shells like ksh93 or bash.

Comment: Thanks. No, it's just that I like simple shells. There's just too many things going on with, for example, completions and other "magical" things that _I don't fully understand_. So it's just another case of being afraid of the unknown, I suppose. Personal opinion, obviously. [Ref](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg01184.html), [Ref](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg01190.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super clear on what you are asking for, but if you want the user to be able to enter multiple lines and then process all the lines as a whole you can use `mapfile`.  It takes in user input until EOF is encountered and then returns an array with each line being an item in the array.

**PROGRAM.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunction () {
    echo "$@"
}

SENTANCE=''
echo "Enter your input, press ctrl+D when finished"
mapfile input   #this takes user input until they terminate with ctrl+D
n=0
for line in "${input[@]}"
do
    ((n++))
    SENTANCE+="\n$n\t$(myfunction $line)"
done
echo -e "$SENTANCE"
```

**Example**

```
$: bash PROGRAM.sh
Enter your input, press ctrl+D when finished
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is not line 10
# I pushed ctrl+d here

1   this is line 1
2   this is line 2
3   this is not line 10
```

Comment: doesn't work, `input` variable returns just the first line

Comment: There was a " missing... I've updated the code to make  how it works a little more clear